# I have got 255 302 redirect pages on Magento

Tags: magento-1.9

I was trying to add https to my website but after adding https, found out that the website didn't have SSL certificate. Then I removed the https from the website using cpanel. Now after I did the site audit, it shows me that there are 257 pages have temporary redirects and 1119 images don't have alt attributes. Can someone please help me on how to solve this problem.